# Configure json on Play framework (scala)

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Checking [play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonAutomated) I found that we can automate json de/serizalization with the following code:

```
implicit val addressWrites = Json.writes[Address]
implicit val addressReads = Json.reads[Address]
```

A friend told me to add this on a companion object, but then should I add one companion obj for each class only to add the json config? Couldn't I add all my models in just one place or use some annotations on each class as in java?

and about general config like:
    implicit val config = JsonConfiguration(SnakeCase)

where could I add that?

Comment: The good practice in Scala is to have the typeclass instances (such as JSON `Reads` and `Writes`) for `YourType` in the companion object of this `YourType`, not only but also to benefit from the default resolution rules of the implicit scope. So code required to define such instances (as configuration) should follow the same rules.

Comment: @cchantep could you give me an example in code?

Comment: There are various Play and Scala examples around. You have to be more specific.